# typedef in VC++ & boost

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I'm learning about boost multiIndex and I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html).

The problem is that I cannot compile the code from the Hashed Indices section (the first block of code on that page) using Visual Studio 2008 :(

Every time I try, the c++ compiler complains:

```
main.cpp(19) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
main.cpp(19) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Those errors occur at the typedef on line 19 in the block of code shown above. Can someone help me shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in that example has an implied using directive -- `using namespace boost::multi_index;`.

Either add said using directive before the `typedef`, or fully qualify `multi_index_container`, `indexed_by`, `ordered_unique`, `hashed_unique`, etc.

Comment: I feel so silly, thank you very much, that was indeed my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Their code sample doesn't include the necessary namespaces, which I think is your problem. Try adding

```
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::multi_index;
```

before the code given.

Answer (score 1):

It's a namespace problem.  You'll need a boost:: in front of that multi_index_container and indexed_by and everything else you're pulling from boost.